# Changing font (Trebuchet MS, Calibari) in Excel programmatically C#

Tags: c#, office-interop

I am currently working in a C# application which has a class which will generate an excel file. Everything went smooth. The data populated on the excel sheet has 'Times New Roman' has font. I would like to change it to some other fonts (Calibari). How can I do that programmatically.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is how:

```
    //Declare Excel Interop variables
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;

    //Initialize variables
    xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass();
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
    xlWorkSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

    //Set global attributes
    xlApp.StandardFont = "Arial Narrow";
    xlApp.StandardFontSize = 10;
```

Focus on the 2nd line from the bottom. That sets the default font type, but I wanted to show you where xlApp came from, even if it's self explanatory.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me using the Microsoft Excel 14.0 Object Library.

Answer (score 17):

From what I tried, simply changing font name, size etc... on range changes font for that range:

```
range.Font.Name = "Arial"
range.Font.Size = 10
range.Font.Bold = true
```

Answer (score 4):

the following worked for me, when I tried setting the default application font it did nothing so I was able to set the font name of the active sheet rows and it worked. Also worth noting I used and tested this using Excel Interop version 12

```
Excel.Application excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
//Create\Add workbook object
Excel.Workbooks workBooks = excelApp.Workbooks;
//Excel.Workbook
Excel.Workbook workBook = workBooks.Add(Excel.XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet);
//use worksheet object 
Excel.Worksheet workSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)excelApp.ActiveSheet;
//set default font
workSheet.Rows.Font.Name = "Arial";
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried something like this:

```
new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold);
```

Comment: _range.Font = new Font("Arial", 16, FontStyle.Bold);
It didn't work.

Comment: Have you tried it in your code context? See how .NET works with Font classes and how it builds a 'fonty' text.

Answer (score 3):

```
var range = worksheet.get_Range(string.Format("{0}:{0}", startRowIndex, Type.Missing));
            range = range.EntireRow;
            range.Style.Font.Name = "Arial";
            range.Style.Font.Bold = false;
            range.Style.Font.Size = 12;
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey Do not upset I do it and works for me .

Just define Font.Name and excell sheet fill all sheet use everywhere .
Any Way Code is :

```
 workSheet.Range[workSheet.Cells[1, tempCount], workSheet.Cells[1, tempCount + mergeCount-1]].Merge();
                workSheet.Range[workSheet.Cells[1, tempCount], workSheet.Cells[1, tempCount + mergeCount - 1]].Interior.Color = ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.FromArgb(23,65,59));
                workSheet.Range[workSheet.Cells[1, tempCount], workSheet.Cells[1, tempCount + mergeCount - 1]].Borders.LineStyle = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
                workSheet.Range[workSheet.Cells[1, tempCount], workSheet.Cells[1, tempCount + mergeCount - 1]].Style.Font.Name = "Arial Narrow";
```

Answer (score 1):

((Excel.Range)WorksheetResult.UsedRange).Font.Name = "Avant Garde";

WorksheetResult is just a sheet reference.

Answer (score 0):

Found this thread by my own similar problem. I had a little picker box that, when a cell was clicked, needed to paste a unique font's symbol into the selected excel cell. Here's how i did that:

```
string selectedItem = arrayOfSymbols[tableLayoutPanel1.GetRow((Control)sender), tableLayoutPanel1.GetColumn((Control)sender)];

Excel.Worksheet ws = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveSheet;
Excel.Range cell = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveCell;

ws.Cells[cell.Row, cell.Column].Font.Name = "My Custom Font";
ws.Cells[cell.Row, cell.Column] = selectedItem;
```