# How to set font family to Arial in excel for used range excel inter op using C#

Tags: c#, excel, font-family

Hi I am trying to use font family Arial but it is not working with excel interop C#

```
sheet.Rows.Font.FontStyle = "Arial";
```

I am using Fontname property also it is not working could please suggest the solution for this.

Thanks

Comment: [Changing font (Trebuchet MS, Calibari) in Excel programmatically C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627658/changing-font-trebuchet-ms-calibari-in-excel-programmatically-c-sharp)

Comment: Thanks It was helpfull